# Does it safe to convert bytes to string with UTF8 encoding?

Tags: c#, utf-8

Today I saw a question with code like this:

```
var accumulator = "";
var buffer = new byte[8192];
while (true)
{
    var readed = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    accumulator += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, readed);
    if (readed < buffer.Length)
        break;
}
var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(accumulator);
```

I know that this code is inefficient but does it safe? Is there some byte sequence that break the result?

Comment: Anything that splits a codepoint across an 8192-byte boundary will fail, yes. Why decode as UTF-8 just to immediately re-encode?

Comment: No it is not safe. Better way would be `accumulator = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEnd()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code is obviously broken; if this was proposed as an answer then you should bring the bug to the attention of the author.

UTF-8 sequences can be more than one byte, obviously. If there is a multiple-byte sequence that starts at the end of the current buffer and resumes at the start of the following buffer, then the translation of each buffer to a string will be wrong.

Comment: "was proposed as an answer" - no, this code is from question. From your answer I understood a possible bug in that approach. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The safe way to do this is to use a stateful UTF8 decoder, which can be obtained from `Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder()`.

The stateful decoder will internally keep bytes that correspond to an incomplete multi-byte sequence. The next time you give it more bytes, it'll finish the sequence and return the character(s) that it decoded from the sequence.

Below is an example of how to use it. In my implementation, I use a `char[]` buffer that is sized such that we'll always have enough room to store a full conversion of X number of bytes. This way, we only perform two memory allocations to read an entire stream.

```
public static string ReadStringFromStream( Stream stream )
{
    // --- Byte-oriented state ---
    // A nice big buffer for us to use to read from the stream.
    byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[8192];

    // --- Char-oriented state ---
    // Gets a stateful UTF8 decoder that holds onto unused bytes when multi-byte sequences
    // are split across multiple byte buffers.
    var decoder = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();

    // Initialize a char buffer, and make it large enough that it will be able to fit
    // a full reads-worth of data from the byte buffer without needing to be resized.
    char[] charBuffer = new char[Encoding.UTF8.GetMaxCharCount( byteBuffer.Length )];

    // --- Output ---
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    // --- Working state ---
    int bytesRead;
    int charsConverted;
    bool lastRead = false;

    do
    {
        // Read a chunk of bytes from our stream.
        bytesRead = stream.Read( byteBuffer, 0, byteBuffer.Length );

        // If we read 0 bytes, we hit the end of stream.
        // We're going to tell the converter to flush, and then we're going to stop.
        lastRead = ( bytesRead == 0 );

        // Convert the bytes into characters, flushing if this is our last conversion.
        charsConverted = decoder.GetChars( 
            byteBuffer, 
            0, 
            bytesRead, 
            charBuffer, 
            0, 
            lastRead 
        );

        // Build up a string in a character buffer.
        stringBuilder.Append( charBuffer, 0, charsConverted );
    }
    while( lastRead == false );

    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel(assuming it is working), See "L.B"'s comment

Comment: @EZI - Sure, but this demonstrates how to do it yourself, and thus, gives you something you can adapt to your circumstance if you do not want to read until the end of the stream or have other different requirements. Nothing wrong with pulling the curtain back a little, every once in a while.